# Select specific annotation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I'm looping through SQLite results and add annotations to a map

```
 while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

     double latitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0);
     double longitude = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 1);

     MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

     CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
     location.latitude = latitude;
     location.longitude = longitude;
     [point setCoordinate:(location)];
     [point setTitle:venuename];
     [point setSubtitle:@"hello"];

     [mapView addAnnotation:point];

     [point release];

 }
```

Works great. Now, lets say I want to Select the 3nd Annotation, I do

```
id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:2];    
[mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:NO];
```

However, it seems annotations are added to the map in random order, and not according to the order of my loop. So the "objectAtIndex:2" is always a different annotation, and not the second Database result.

Is there a way how I can give an annotation some unique ID before I add them to the map, which I can then use to select them ?

Answer (score 3):

An annotation can be any custom object that you want, provide it conforms to the MKAnnotation Protocol ([see here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html))

So if you need your annotations to have an ID, you can declare a property for it in the code for the custom annotation object.

Comment: Ok i've added an ID to the annotation object `(@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *annotationid;)` and I'm now adding my annotations like this:  `MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:venuename andCoordinate:location andid:thisid];`  so they have an ID.  But how would this line have to look to e.g. call the Annotation with the "annotationid" 23 ? `id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
                [mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:NO];`

Comment: you can cycle through the annotations and find the one with the ID you want. `for(MapViewAnnotation *annotation in mapView.annotations){ if(annotation.id == 23);}`